# How to set all processors or groups as a whole to support transaction in Nifi?

Tags: transactions, apache-nifi

There two Processor put data into DB,and one succeeded,but another failed.
However,I want to they would fail or succeed together as a complete unit.
Does Nifi 1.9.2 support this?

Can you show some advices?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processors are independent of each other and cannot act as a transaction together.